# Problem with installing Qt5.3

Tags: 14.04, gui, qt, c++, qt5

I am trying to install Qt5.3 into my Ubuntu 14.04(64 bit). While installation process was running suddenly it was showing some prompts and showed several error messages as following:

```
Error during installation process (qt.53.doc):
Error while extracting 'installer://qt.53.doc/5.3.1-0qt5_docs.7z': Could not open file: /opt/Qt5.3.1/Docs/Qt-5.3/qtwidgets/images/windowflags_previewwindow.png (Unknown error)


Error during installation process (qt.53.doc):
Error while extracting 'installer://qt.53.doc/5.3.1-0qt5_docs.7z': Could not open file:  (No file name specified)


Error during installation process (qt.53.doc):
Could not create folder : Unknown error.


Error during installation process (qt.53.examples):
Error while extracting 'installer://qt.53.examples/5.3.1-0qt5_examples.7z': Could not open file:  (No file name specified)


Error during installation process (qt.53.gcc_64):
Error while extracting 'installer://qt.53.gcc_64/5.3.1-0icu_52_1_ubuntu_11_10_64.7z': Could not open file:  (No file name specified)


Error during installation process (qt.53.gcc_64):
Error while extracting 'installer://qt.53.gcc_64/5.3.1-0qt5_addons.7z': Could not open file:  (No file name specified)

Error during installation process (qt.53.gcc_64):
Error while extracting 'installer://qt.53.gcc_64/5.3.1-0qt5_essentials.7z': Could not open file:  (No file name specified)


Error during installation process (qt.53.gcc_64):
File '' does not exist or is not an executable binary.


Error during installation process (qt.53.gcc_64):
QMake from the current Qt version 
(/opt/Qt5.3.1/5.3/gcc_64/bin/qmake)is not existing. Please file a bugreport with this dialog at https://bugreports.qt-project.org.
```

For the first error "'installer://qt.53.doc/5.3.1-0qt5_docs.7z': Could not open file", I've checked is there 7zip installed into my machine or not..But 7zip was installed. I cant recognize the other errors.

How do I fix it?